# How to unlet a variable in Vim 9 script?

Tags: variables, vim9script, vim9

> In Vim9 script `:let` cannot be used.  An existing variable is assigned to
> without any command.  The same for global, window, tab, buffer and Vim
> variables, because they are not really declared.  Those can also be deleted
> with `:unlet`.
>
> *https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html*

The quotation above is not really clear to me. Here is a part of my .vimrc, how can I unlet `skip_defaults_vim`?

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
    # Load defaults.vim even if system-wide .vimrc has been found
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Global variables are still the same as in legacy script, so unlet works as before. The only difference is that the prefix `g:` now is always required to access global variables.
2. Unletting non-existent variable is pretty much like talking to invisible friend.
3. Translating vimrc into Vim9 script / Lua / whatever is a waste of time.

Comment: > Unletting non-existent variable is pretty much like talking to invisible friend.

Why you gotta say it like that.

> Translating vimrc into Vim9 script / Lua / whatever is a waste of time.

Quite literally. Because you have already done the work. Why would you *ever* wanna do something you've already done?

Comment: Matt, but why `unlet! skip_defaults_vim` gives me an error?

Comment: @user90726 Because you can't unlet _local_ variable (this is compiled language, remember?). In VimScript it defaults to global, in Vim9 script it defaults to local.

Comment: Sorry for a late comment (I was in a hospital these days, after a kind of "street fight" with two idiots), but then another question: what I need to do in such a case? Because it is now local and therefore I cannot unlet it, what is the new way to load `defaults.vim` even if system-wide `.vimrc` has been found? Well, this might be better to open a separate question to ask this.

Comment: (I mean, if I really want to translate the existing `.vimrc` into Vim 9 script.)

Comment: @user90726 1) You don't need to unlet it, as it does not exist (unless **you created** it earlier and I guess it is not the case); 2) If you really need to unlet global variable then you **must** mark it is global one, i.e. use `g:` prefix. In legacy script it was optional, now it is required.